# Forcing dictionary to tuple to use with endwith on string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Given dictionary:

```
dictMnths = dict((v,k) for k,v in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr))
```

I would liker to use the `dictMonths` similarly to the tuple `('Jan','Feb')` below:

```
'aaFeb'.endswith(('Jan','Feb'))
# True
```

## Attempts

### `keys()`

```
'aaFeb'.endswith(dictMnths.keys())
# TypeError: endswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not dict_keys
```

### `str()`

```
'aaFeb'.endswith(str(dictMnths.keys()))
# False
```

This is not desired answer as `dictMonths` contains `Feb`.

Comment: If i'm not wrong, `dict.keys()` is a proxy to the actual data (in Python 3, in version 2.x it returns a list). That's why it tells you its from type `dict_keys`. try to cast it into tuple `tuple(dictMnths.keys))`

Comment: I don't know if this is intended, but be aware that your dictionary will have an empty string as one of the keys, so every string will end with that.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Well spotted, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tuple()` should help.

```
import calendar
dictMnths = dict((v,k) for k,v in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr))
print('aaFeb'.endswith(tuple( dictMnths.keys()))) # or 'aaFeb'.endswith(tuple(filter(None, dictMnths.keys())))
```

**Output:**

```
True
```

**Note:** I used `filter(None, dictMnths.keys())` just to remove empty elements.

Comment: Or they could just use `enumerate(calendar.month_abbr[1:], 1)` to avoid the empty string

Comment: @Duncan. Thanks i agree filter is not required. I just pasted it as an fyi.